# Checking number in a vector and replace it with either 0 or 1

Tags: matlab

I have a vertical vector that has some numbers the maximum of these number is repeated couple of times for example [1 0 3 2 3 1]. So, I created a for loop to check for the maximum and replace this maximum with "1" and the other number with "0". This is the code I am using

```
maxVal = max(Output);
for k= 1:coloumns
    if Output[k] = maxVal;
        Output_bin[k] = 1;
    else
        Output_bin[k] = 0;
    end
end
```

However, when I use this code I get this error "Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket." at the line of 'Output_bin[k] = 1;'. Does somebody know why I am getting this error.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: MATLAB indexes numeric arrays with parentheses, not brackets.

Comment: When I changed them to () the error was removed, yet, Output_bin is all zeros knowing that Output have some maximum values and some smaller numbers. I also tried using the condition 'if Output[k] == maxVal' but still the Output_bin is zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> check for the maximum and replace this maximum with "1" and the other
>   number with "0"

```
A=[1 0 3 2 3 1]';
B=A;
A(A==max(A))=1;
A(B<max(B))=0
```

gives

```
A =

 0
 0
 1
 0
 1
 0
```

Or (might be faster)

```
A=[1 0 3 2 3 1]';
B=zeros(length(A),1);
B(A==max(A))=1
```

Comment: Or `A=[1 0 ...` etc. then `C=A==max(A)`

Answer (score 0):

Yours if statement is not valid as well. If If you still want to use a for-loops:

```
maxVal = max(Output);
Output_bin=zeros(size(Output));
for k= 1:length(Output(1,:))
    if Output(k)== maxVal
        Output_bin(k) = 1;
    end
end
```

But you can also vectorize it as in Nasser example.

```
Output(Output<max(Output))=0;
Output(Output>0)=1
```

Comment: When I used the '==' I didn't work as well, however, the answer of Nasser worked. But do you know why the '==' didn't work as my guess is that it should work as well.

Comment: Issue probably in definition of your columns. I have made edits so it should work fine.